# ruby - alternative to using eval to assign object variables from xml data

Tags: ruby

I'm pulling info out of an xml blob and assigning it to an [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html). I want to assign fields to the openstruct with the same name as the xml field.

Right now I'm using eval like so:

```
  vehicles = []
  xml['vehicles'].each do |vv|
    infos = OpenStruct.new
    ['model','vehicleIdentifier','make','modelYear'].each do |iid|
      eval("infos.#{iid} = vv['#{iid}']")
    end 
    vehicles << infos
  end
```

Any suggestions on how to do it without using `eval`?

Thanks!

Comment: could you add a representative part of the XML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason to use `eval` here. Everything you need is already available. The standard form is simply:

```
infos[iid] = v[iid]
```

This is because `iid` is just a string. Doing things like `eval("v['#{iid}'])` is making things way, way more complicated than they need to be.

You can also refine this code by recognizing that the list of keys never changes, so that can be made a constant, and that your OpenStruct object can be composed based on a simple mapping:

```
XML_KEYS = %w[ model vehicleIdentifier make modelYear ]
```

Later in your method:

```
OpenStruct.new(
  XML_KEYS.map do |iid|
    [ iid, vv[iid] ]
  end.to_h
)
```

You can apply that `map` technique on a broader level too:

```
vehicles = xml['vehicles'].map do |vv|
  OpenStruct.new(
    XML_KEYS.map do |iid|
      [ iid, vv[iid] ]
    end.to_h
  )
end
```

Where that can side-step the need to create a variable and then force-populate it with `<<`.

The key to using Ruby effectively is to identify when you can do things as a series of simple transformations with [Enumberable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html)-type tools instead of doing it the hard, procedural way other languages dictate by their design.

Answer (score 1):

How about taking out `eval` and using the `[]` assignment syntax instead?

```
 vehicles = []
 xml['vehicles'].each do |vv|
   infos = OpenStruct.new
   ['model','vehicleIdentifier','make','modelYear'].each do |iid|
     infos[iid] = vv[iid]
   end 
   vehicles << infos
 end

 vehicles.first.model # => vehicle model
```

You will still be able to access this information on `infos` in the method form as shown above. As shown in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)